# How to omit an empty line after a for loop in Jinja?

Tags: jinja2, jinja2-cli

I would like to generate the following output with the [j2cli](https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli):

```js
// before
function (arg1,
          arg2,
          arg3)
// after
```

I tried the following template:

```
// before
function ({% for param in ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'] -%}
          {{param}}{{"," if not loop.last else ")"}}
          {% endfor %}
// after
```

But it produces always an additional empty line at the end:

```js
// before
function (arg1,
          arg2,
          arg3)
          
// after
```

When I try this template:

```
// before
function ({% for param in ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'] -%}
          {{param}}{{"," if not loop.last else ")"}}
          {% endfor -%}
// after
```

The comment gets indented.

```js
// before
function (arg1,
          arg2,
          arg3)
          // after
```

This one

```
// before
function ({% for param in ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'] %}
          {{param}}{{"," if not loop.last else ")"}}
          {%- endfor %}
// after
```

removes the empty line at the end but produces one at the beginning.

```js
// before
function (
          arg1,
          arg2,
          arg3)
// after
```

And this one

```
// before
function ({% for param in ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'] -%}
          {{param}}{{"," if not loop.last else ")"}}
          {%- endfor %}
// after
```

removes all whitespace.

```js
// before
function (arg1,arg2,arg3)
// after
```

How to format the function correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it: (sometimes it helps to sleep one night)

```
// before
function ({% for param in ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'] -%}
          {{param}}{% if not loop.last %},
          {% endif %}
          {%- endfor %})
// after
```

The default of Jinja's `for` loop does not help here, because it formats every line in the same way. Either at the beginning of every loop or at the end it keeps the combination of newline+indent. But before the first line and after the last line newline+indent are unwanted. The lines can not be formatted uniformly.

So the solution is to disable the default whitespace handling of the `for` loop `{% for -%}...{%- endfor %}` and generate newline+indent after every but the last line manually.

This is possibly by aligning the `endif` in the same column as the `{{param}}`. The `-` of the `endfor` just prevents the generation of whitespace and eats the whitespace after the `endif` but does not eat the whitespace generated by the body of the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

I've got working example only with [custom config](https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli#customization):

`j2_custom.py`:

```py
def j2_environment_params():
    """ Extra parameters for the Jinja2 Environment """
    # Jinja2 Environment configuration
    # http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Environment
    return dict(
        # Remove whitespace around blocks
        trim_blocks=True,
        lstrip_blocks=True,
    )
```

`j2-template.j2`:

```py
// before
function ({% for param in ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'] %}
{{"          " if not loop.first else ""}}{{param}}{{"," if not loop.last else ")"}}
          {% endfor %}
// after
```

cli call:

```sh
$ j2 j2-template.j2 --customize j2_custom.py
// before
function (arg1,
          arg2,
          arg3)
// after
```

---

There is [white-space control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#whitespace-control) where you could control `lstrip_blocks` and `trim_blocks` manually in template via `+` and `-`, but I did not find working example with them.